# Gridview onRowCommand fired gridview no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvWorkshop" runat="server" 
              AllowCustomPaging="True" AllowPaging="True"
              BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
              AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              DataKeyNames="ID, ctrycode" OnRowCommand="gvWorkshop_onRowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="paddress" HeaderText="Address" />
        </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void gvWorkshop_onRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
   int index;
   string ID;
   GridViewRow row;
   if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
   {
      index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      row = gvWorkshop.Rows[index];
      ID = gvWorkshop.DataKeys[grdrow.RowIndex]["workshopID"].ToString();
   }
 }
```

I get error index out of range because the gridview is empty.  Any one has idea whats go wrong?  WHy the gridview become empty.  Please help.

Comment: where do you bind your gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line

```
ID = gvWorkshop.DataKeys[grdrow.RowIndex]["workshopID"].ToString();
```

You have mention "grdrow" in place of "row". please change it to

```
 ID = gvWorkshop.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["workshopID"].ToString();
```

Comment: the problem is in row = gvWorkshop.Rows[index]; it show index was out of range.

Comment: I try this and i can get the ID, but after that my gridview is missing.

Comment: please update your designer code.bcoz you are checking e.CommandName == "Edit" but you have not mention in designer.